# composition of covering map and bundle projection

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Hello, can somebody help with the following question that I have thought over for quite some time, to no avail?

Suppose f: X--->Y is a universal cover and g: Y--->Z a fiber bundle, where X, Y and Z are manifolds. Is the composition gof: X--->Z necessarily a fiber bundle?

THanks!

Comment: This question is more interesting than I thought.  I probably just repeated several of your mistakes in attempting to answer, before realizing the issue, though I can't come up with a counterexample quickly.  Could you say a little about what you have done to help others avoid the traps?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Elizabeth. Please see Torsten's answer to avoid all traps at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to just assume that $f$ is a covering space. By shrinking $Z$ we may assume that that $Z$ is a ball and that $Y=Z\times F$. As $X\to Y$ is a covering space and $Z$ is simply-connected there is a covering space $X'\to F$ such that $X\to Y$ is isomorphic to $Z\times X'\to Z\times F$ which gives what you want.

**Addendum**: The reason that $X'$ exists is that if $h\colon T\to T'$ is a homotopy equivalence (and possibly $T$ and $T'$ fulfil some local niceness conditions which certainly are fulfilled in the case at hand), then pullback along $h$ induces an equivalence between the category of covering spaces of $T$ and that of $T'$. This is true irregardless on whether $T$ and $T'$ are connected or not.

Comment: What is $F\hspace{.04 in}$?

Comment: obviously the fiber.

Comment: Thanks to Torsten's answer. The existence of $X'$ is especially enlightening.

Comment: As I tried to unravel Torsten's concise proof today, I found myself unable to prove the existence of $X'$. The difficulty lies in that one really needs to argue locally and there is no guarantee that the total space of the cover is connected, which needs to be true for the existence of $X'$. Could Torsten elaborate on why $X'$ must exist? Thanks.

Comment: Still don't understand. Torsten seems to be saying  if $X \rightarrow Z \times F$ is a covering, then $\exists$ a covering $F' \rightarrow F$ such that $X \cong Z \times F'$. I can prove the existence of $F'$, but am unable to demonstrate a homeomorphism $X \cong Z \times F'$, unless $X$ is connected (so that covering space theory applies).

Comment: I think I get it now. I also think that one needs to assume the base space Z is connected so that the fibers associated with the various local neighborhoods are homeomorphic.

Comment: Two things. One doesn't need a connected base to have a covering space theory and what I said about a homotopy equivalence inducing a category equivalence is true in general. Also that $Z$ is connected is part of the condition that $Z$ be contractible (or just simply connected).

Comment: To Torsten: Thanks for your explanation. I think your argument is really a local one, in view of the words "By shrinking $Z$", where you needn't worry about the fibers being the same. But once you have dealt with local neighborhoods, you need worry about whether the fibers in the various neighborhoods are homeomorphic so that you do get a universal typical fiber, which is required in the definition of fiber bundle. And I think connectedness of the base is a sufficient condition (so that every two neighborhoods are connected by a finite chain of neighborhoods).

Comment: It depends on your definition of fibration, I have used the one which says that it locally is a product. (You did say fibre bundle though which is more likely to mean one where all the fibres are the same.) It is then a fact that you have the same fibre if the base is connected. Without that condition I am not totally sure the statement is true. In any case that is something I think is most easily shown *a posteriori*.